# cuda error at cuctxcreate launch failed

Tags: rendering, gpu

[image]

I have been getting a launch error when i try to render a scene using my GPU.

I use a GTX 1070 on blender 2.78 and the scene is very simplistic so there should be plenty of memory available. Any Idea what is going on?

Comment: Check this: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2261/blender-is-currently-unusable-on-nvidia-gpus-m-mx-family

Comment: Simply restarting Blender fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have a GTX 770 and I was having the same error but I was trying to use "Branched Path Tracing" instead of "Path Tracing" under sampling. I was able to cure it by turning down my tile my tile size under performance. I set my tile size to 64x64. I tested several different sizes up to 128x128(Mine would crash at any size larger) but 64x64 was by far the fastest on my GTX 770 2GB. It may be different on your GTX 1070. I also couldn't see what your sampling is set to so this might not even apply to what you're experiencing. It wouldn't hurt to try smaller tile sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Change .. Render > Performance > Start Resolution  to 256 or 128 if u are using higer..Because GPU cant not handled.

Comment: Could you please expand and clarify on what you are talking about to other users who may not understand Blender as well as we do? I know what you are talking about but others might not be able to follow along. A picture is worth 1,000 words sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error after changing transparency maximum bounces from 8 to 64 in the Light Paths panel and keyframing some material's transparency factor. I saved the project, **restarted blender** and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

mine using Blender 2.83 and got this error too. it happens when rendering architecture scene with lots of geometry. solution for me is using cpu render (not using GPU), the result is 25% slower but it works

in Scene > Render > Device change to CPU[image]