# CUDA Timeout Error

Tags: rendering, gpu

I am getting an error message that does not allow me to render my file using my GPU. Please Help!

"cuda error at cuctxcreate: launch exceeded timeout"

**UPDATE:** 
I thought I solved the problem but it is still occuring with a new error message.

bpy.context.space_data.context = 'WORLD' bpy.ops.world.new() bpy.ops.world.new() bpy.data.node_groups["Shader Nodetree"].nodes["Background"].inputs[0].default_value = (0.774277, 0.774277, 0.774277, 1) bpy.data.node_groups["Shader Nodetree"].nodes["Background"].inputs[0].default_value = (0.774277, 0.774277, 0.774277, 1) bpy.context.space_data.context = 'RENDER' CUDA error at cuCtxCreate: Launch failed

Comment: Should I post the file?

Comment: Have a look to the console window to see if there is additional information about your issue

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lukeg\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\addons\Dynamic Sky.py", line 378, in draw
    if bpy.data.worlds['Dynamic']:
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "Dynamic" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1

Comment: Is the GPU rendering ok with the same scene but without dynamic sky? Or is rendering with dynamic sky ok with another scene? And also look at this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73434/cuda-error-at-cuctxcreate-launch-failed