# How do I escape from the cancel status?

Tags: rendering, interface

I accidentally entered this mode, I don't know even that this is a mode or something. Anyway, I'm in the situation like below:
[image: Cancel what?]

Even though I'm in the rendered mode, nothing is rendered. How can I fix that? I've googled with several keywords but couldn't find yet...

Comment: It looks to me like it is rendering. Just press z choose another mode and see if it goes away. 
By default you are rendering a cube in a gray environment, which looks exactly like your screenshot.

Comment: I tried it, but nothing happened... in other modes like solid, wireframe, look-dev everything is rendered fine

Comment: I'm confused. Is your problem that you can't switch modes, because it always says 'cancel' or is it why does rendermode look like that?
As I said, this is how rendered mode looks like in a new scene.

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz My problem was that the donut in the center of the screen is not rendered at all as you can see, it's not a new scene. I found that the issue is caused by crashing from `cuda error at cuctxcreate launch failed`. So I restart the blender and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is somewhat related to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73434/cuda-error-at-cuctxcreate-launch-failed). I solved this by restarting the blender in the end...